# Communicate between plugins

Tags: plugin-development

I have created two WordPress plugins. If both plugins are installed, some beneficial cooperation could take place between the two.

So my question: what is the best way to get them to work together? How do I detect a certain plugin is enabled? How do I transmit information? I suppose I could use globals, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question depends a lot on what you want to do ..

But in general , when a plugin is loaded or executed, the functions are being "registered" in PHP server and are available for all to use (depending of course HOW you write them) ...

So for example, to detect if a plugin is enabled or installed, the other plugin could have

`if (function_exists('NameOfFunctionFromPlugin1')`

there is also a wordpress function to check plugin activation

```
<?php is_plugin_active($plugin) ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

as for "transmitting Info" : Because the functions are available, you could use them. so for example, a value that is returned from a certain function in one plugin, can be evoked by the other , calling this function , and getting the value returned for use .

Comment: Of course, I was trying to make this far too complicated. Thanks for the answer